# Is using ctx.channel.fetch_member() safe

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to get and send users avatar from another guild, I have a way it works, but it says `This method is an API call. For general usage, consider get_member() instead.` in the docs. Im wondering if it could be unsafe since I am using an user account, because making a bot without a good server is boring.

```python
@bot.command(usage="test2", description="test")
async def test2(ctx, user):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print(ctx.guild)
    for x in bot.guilds:
        print(x.name)
        user = x.get_member(user)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            await ctx.send(user.avatar_url)
```

^^ I tried using `get_member()`, but that did not work, it failed to find the user. ^^

```python
@bot.command(usage="test2", description="test")
async def test2(ctx, user:discord.User):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(user.avatar_url)

@bot.command(usage="test2", description="test")
async def test2(ctx, user:discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(user.avatar_url)
```

^^ Both `discord.User` and `discord.Member` fail to find. ^^

```python
@bot.command(usage="test2", description="test")
async def test2(ctx, user):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print(ctx.guild)
    for x in bot.guilds:
        print(x.name)
        user = await x.fetch_member(user)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            await ctx.send(user.avatar_url)
            break
```

^^ Using `fetch_member()` works fine, but im wondering if its safe for an non bot account. ^^

```python
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.flags import Intents

import json
import os

def configgg():
    paath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + r"\data\config.json"
    if os.path.exists(paath):
        with open(paath) as cock:
            data = json.load(cock)
            global __token__
            __token__ =data['token']
            global __prefix__
            __prefix__ =data['prefix']

configgg()

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=__prefix__, self_bot=True, case_insensitive=True, intents = intents, guild_subscriptions=True)

@bot.command(usage="test2", description="test")
async def test2(ctx, user):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print(ctx.guild)
    for x in bot.guilds:
        print(x.name)
        user = x.get_member(user)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            await ctx.send(user.avatar_url)

bot.run(__token__, bot=False)
```

^^ Here's a short version of all the code incase I missed something in intents or something? ^^

Comment: There is nothing unsafe about it, it just takes longer. If you have the client-side data readily available in `bot.users` or `guild.members` then it's faster to retrieve the data that way. If not, then you can make a server side request with `fetch_member`

Answer (score 0):

First off: Be advised that self-bots aka logging in with a user token is **against [Discord ToS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352)** and can get you banned if they catch it.

---

`get_member()` not working properly is also likely an effect of you logging in with a user token - this method uses a client-side member cache that is only populated with the privileged members intent that needs to be manually enabled in the developer portal for any application. For obvious reasons, that is impossible for a user.

Both for ToS compliance as well as performance reasons, I can only advise you to use a proper bot account, enable the members intent and go for `get_member()` from there.